# Аутентификация в WCF-сервисе через SoapHeader

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, веб-служба

На сервисе:

```
class MyService : IMyService
{
    public Authentication Authenticator { get; set; } = new Authentication();

    [OperationContract]
    [WebMethod]
    [SoapHeader("Authenticator")]
    public string SimpleMethod(string attr1, string documentNumber, string attr2)
    {
        if (Authenticator.Login != "super_user" || Authenticator.Password != "super_password") return "Auth Error!";
        return attr1+attr2;
    }
}

//пробовал здесь использовать атрибуты DataContract и DataMember, не помогло
public class Authentication : SoapHeader
{
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Login { get; set; }
}
```

С клиента отправляю запрос так:
Реализация выбрана в связи с тем, что мой сервис тестовый, в реальности нужно работать с сервисом о котором известна только его сигнатура методов, а url, логин и пароль будут подставляться динамически. В данном примере извне подставляются url, namespace и имя сервиса, логин и пароль.

```
public string Invoke() 
{
    string soapStr =
        @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
        <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" 
           xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" 
           xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">
          <soap:Header>
            <Authentication xmlns=""{0}"" soap:mustUnderstand=""0"">
              <Login xmlns=""http://tempuri.org/"">{1}</Login>
              <Password xmlns=""http://tempuri.org/"">{2}</Password>
            </Authentication>
          </soap:Header>
          <soap:Body>
            <SimpleMethod xmlns=""{0}"">
              <attr1>hello!</attr1>
              <attr2>world!</attr2>
            </SimpleMethod>
          </soap:Body>
        </soap:Envelope>";

        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url);
        req.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", $"\"{nameSpace}{serviceName}/" + "SimpleMethod" + "\"");
        req.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
        req.Accept = "text/xml";
        req.Method = "POST";

        using (Stream stm = req.GetRequestStream())
        {
            soapStr = string.Format(soapStr,nameSpace,login,password);
            using (StreamWriter stmw = new StreamWriter(stm))
            {
                stmw.Write(soapStr);
            }
        }


        try
        {
            using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
            {
                return responseReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return e.Message;
        }
  }
```

Без аутентификации методы работают прекрасно, но если добавить header с аутентификацией - хэдер как будто не разбирается. (`Login` и `Password` всегда `null`). Подозреваю, что ошибка в формате отправляемого запроса, но определить ее никак не получается.

Comment: Если у вас `nameSpace != http://tempuri.org/` (из кода непонятно), то вы просто присылаете Login и Password с неверным namespace - `<Login xmlns=""http://tempuri.org/"">{1}</Login>`. Замените на `<Login xmlns=""{0}"">{1}</Login>`

Comment: @PashaPash конкретно в этом случае это `http://tempuri.org/`

Comment: так у вас WCF или старые web services? это немного разные вещи :)

Comment: если у вас WCF - то атрибуты SoapHeader в нем не работают. работу с заголовками в нем придется делать через Message Contract-ы: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/using-message-contracts

Comment: @PashaPash у меня WCF, спасибо за наводку, попробую и отпишусь.